# mod rewrite with three get variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to map the URL

`localhost/abc/meetings/?day=5&month=12&year=2011` to

`localhost/abc/pages/list_meetings.php?day=5&month=12&year=2011`

My Rewrite rule isn't working however,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteRule ^meetings/?day=([0-9]+)&month=([0-9]+)&year=([0-9]+)$ /abc/pages/list_meetings.php?day=$1&month=$2&year=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QSA will automatically append the query string, so you don't need to handle the get variables in your rewrite rule. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteRule ^meetings/$ /abc/pages/list_meetings.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No. You cannot match the query string in a RewriteRule. To match a query string you need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`